# how to add navigator in gridview count creategriditem()

Tags: flutter, gridview, count

I can't navigate another screen with grid view count create griditem ()

how to navigate another screen  i have tried a lot of but can't get it help me for this problem

how to add navigator in this code

first code

```
 child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    createGridItem(0),
                    createGridItem(1),
                    createGridItem(2),
                    createGridItem(3),
                    createGridItem(4),
                    createGridItem(5),

                  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parent with the widget `GestureDeta` like below

```
child: GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
   children: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
           Navigator.push(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewScreen()),
          )
        },
       child: createGridItem(0),
       ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
           Navigator.push(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewScreen()),
          )
        },
       child: createGridItem(1),
       ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
           Navigator.push(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewScreen()),
          )
        },
       child: createGridItem(2),
       ),
],
```

Comment: @daniel. if it is your solution, then please mark as complete, i mean accept the answer, and give me a vote